# Replacing the Timer Interrupt Handler in DOS With GNU (GCC and GAS)

Tags: gcc, assembly, dos, interrupt-handling, gnu-assembler

As the title suggests, I'm trying to replace the existing handler for the Timer interrupt in DOS with one of my own.
After searching far and wide for a variety of solutions, I found some Assembly code which does exactly that, and I have even managed to compile and test it, and saw that it works.

The problem now is that the code I found (see further down) is written for TASM, and I wish to use it with some C code that I'm writing, which I compile with GCC.

I've tried to convert the code into GAS (GNU Assembler) syntax, but I can't seem to get it to work (I mostly experienced crashes of one kind or another during my numerous attempts).

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me with a solution (be it a working version of the assembly code that GAS can compile, a way to do the entire thing in C -- the "interrupt" keyword doesn't work, and neither does "**attribute** ((interrupt))" and the like -- or even a way to bridge between TASM and GCC).

I should also probably mention that the DOS system I'm using is actually an OracleVM VirtualBox Manager running a virtual machine with FreeDOS installed on it, and that the compiler I'm using for C is the GCC that is provided with the DJGPP development environment.

This is the working TASM code I have (taken from http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/x86_asm/276128/276185/re-redefining-the-timer-interrupt-handler/):

```
_stack        SEGMENT    STACK
              db         32 DUP ('STACK   ')
_stack        ENDS



_code        SEGMENT PARA 'CODE'
             ASSUME  CS:_code,  SS:_stack

Lstart  LABEL  NEAR

        JMP    Linstall

;+---------------------------------------------
;| My New 1Ch INT
;| Print 'random' chars to the first video line

new_Int PROC   FAR

        DEC    BYTE PTR CS:Counter

        CLD
        PUSH   AX

        MOV    AX, 0B800h
        MOV    ES,AX                   ; ES = b800h
        MOV    DI,000h                 ; DI = 0000h

        MOV    AH,CS:Counter           ; set foreground and background color
        MOV    AL,CS:Counter           ; set char

        MOV    CX,80
        REP    STOSW                   ; From AX to ES:DI

        POP    AX
        STI

        IRET

new_Int ENDP

Counter DB     0Fh

;+-----------------------------------------
;| Store old INT and Install the new one
;|

Linstall    LABEL    NEAR

old_INT     DD       00000000h

        MOV    AL,01Ch                 ;+-
        MOV    AH,35h                  ;| Save old_INT
        INT    21h                     ;|
        MOV    WORD PTR [old_INT],BX
        MOV    WORD PTR [old_INT][2],ES



        CLI                            ;+-
        PUSH   CS                      ;| Install
        POP    DS                      ;|
        LEA    DX,new_INT
        MOV    AL,1Ch
        MOV    AH,25h
        INT    21h


        MOV    AH,0                    ;+- 
        INT    16H                     ;| Wait for a keypress



;+-----------------------------------------
;| Disinstall and exit

        CLI
        PUSH   DS
        LDS    DX,CS:[old_INT]         ;+- 
        MOV    AL,1Ch                  ;| Disinstall int
        MOV    AH,25h                  ;| 
        INT    21h                     ;| 
        POP    DS
        STI        

        MOV    AL,0                    ;+-
        MOV    AH,4Ch                  ;| Exit 
        INT    21h                     ;| 


_code   ENDS
        END    Lstart
```

It fully works on my machine. I start the program and see the entire first line of the console replaced by colorful characters that change all the time.

And this is my attempt to convert the above code into GAS syntax:

```
.file   "ttv2.s"


# Define a variable for "randomizing" characters and colors
.globl _MyVar
        .section        .bss
_MyVar:
        .space 1
        .section .text


# Define a variable for storing the address of the current ISR
.globl _OldInt
        .section        .bss
        .p2align 2
_OldInt:
        .space 4
        .section .text


# Program entry point
.text
.globl start
start:
        jmp     _Install


# This is the new Interrupt Service Routine that is going to be installed
.globl _NewInt
_NewInt:
        movb    _MyVar,  %al
        decb    %al            # Decrement our variable
        movb    %al,     _MyVar

        cld
        pushw   %ax

        movw    $0xB800, %ax
        movw    %ax,     %es    # ES = 0xB800
        movw    $0,      %di    # DI = 0

        movb    _MyVar,  %ah    # Set the foreground and background colors
        movb    _MyVar,  %al    # Set the charater to be displayed

        movw    $80,     %cx    # The screen is 80 characters wide
        rep     stosw           # Start copying from AX to AS:DI

        popw    %ax
        sti

        iret



.globl _Install
_Install:
        # Save old ISR address
        movb    $0x1C,   %al  # Set the code for the Timer interrupt
        movb    $0x35,   %ah  # 0x35 is the code for getting the current ISR
        int     $0x21         # 0x21 is the interrupt fot s/getting ISRs
        movw    %es,     %dx     #
        shll    $16,     %edx    # Save the address of the
        movw    %bx,     %dx     #  old interrupt handler
        movl    %edx,    _OldInt #


        # Install the new ISR
        cli
        pushw   %cs
        popw    %ds
        lea     _NewInt, %dx  # Set the address of the ISR we're installing
        movb    $0x1C,   %al  # Set the code for the Timer interrupt
        movb    $0x25,   %ah  # 0x25 is the code for setting a new ISR
        int     $0x21         # 0x21 is the interrupt fot s/getting ISRs

        # Wait for a key press
        movl    $0,     %eax
        int     $0x16


.globl _Uninstall
_Uninstall:
        cli
        pushw   %ds
        lds     %cs:_OldInt,    %dx  # Install the address of the old ISR

        movb    $0x1C,   %al  # Set the code for the Timer interrupt
        movb    $0x25,   %ah  # 0x25 is the code for setting a new ISR
        int     $0x21         # 0x21 is the interrupt fot s/getting ISRs

        popw    %ds
        sti


.globl _End
_End:
        # Exit
        movb    $0,     %al
        movb    $0x4C,  %ah   # 0x4C is the code for program exit in DOS
        int     $0x21


        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.5.2"
```

I compile my file (called "ttv2.s") with the following commands:

```
as -o ttv2.o ttv2.s
ld -o ttv2.exe ttv2.o
```

When I run the resulting EXE file (there are no warnings or errors during the assembly and linkage), the program crashes with the error "Exception 0D in ring 0" (and lots of register values).
The TASM version, however, works without a hitch!
So I'm guessing that there is something wrong either with the way I converted the code, or with the way I'm building the final EXE. Or both.

A bit of additional information, should it help in any way:

- If I **remove** the installation commands (the `int $0x21`), there is no crash, and the program waits for me to hit a key and then exits.
- If I **keep** the installation commands, but **remove** the wait-for-key command (the `int $0x16`), the program exits immediately, and there is no crash.
- If I **keep** the installation commands, and **replace** the wait-for-key command with an active delay loop (a simple loop of 4 billion iterations), the program crashes the same way it did when the wait-for-key command was in place, but after a couple of seconds, rather than immediately.
- In both cases with the crash (with the key press or the delay), the program crashes even if I remove just one of the two installation commands.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance, and sorry for the lengthy post...

Comment: Are you sure you're producing a 16-bit executable? "Exception 0D in ring 0" seems to indicate that it's using a dos extender, which you probably don't want in this case.

Comment: Well, the first thing would be to check if you're even running in protected mode (it sounds like you are, but it would be good to double-check).  You can do this with the following commands (they work in a `.code16` section as well if you're on x386 or greater): `movl %cr0, %eax`, `andb $0x1, %al`, `cmpb $0x1, %al` ... if the comparison instruction comes out true, and the first bit of register `CR0` was set, then jump to some code that you can use to give yourself feedback that you're in protected mode vs. real-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify `.code16` so it builds the application for 16-bit real mode.

Comment: `.code16` is probably needed, but I doubt this alone is enough.

Comment: True. I've added `.code16`, and it no longer crashes, but it doesn't _do_ anything, either.
I added the wait-for-keyboard instructions right at the beginning, and when the `.code16` directive is in place, it just doesn't occur.

Comment: I compared the resulting EXE file with the one compiled using TASM, and I noticed that in my EXE, there is an extra command prior to just about everything (opcode 0x66). I understand that GAS adds this in order to be able to perform 32-bit operations in 16-bit mode, but my instructions in that file are purely 16-bit (e.g. `movw $0x50, %cx`).
Is there any way I can get GAS to refrain from adding in these instructions?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're getting an error about rings means that you are for some reason not in 16-bit real mode (like DOS would be run), but rather are in some form of protected mode.  So make sure that 1) you are compiling to 16-bit real mode for your assembly commands (i.e., the binary machine code is 16-bit opcodes, not 32-bit opcodes), and 2) that you are running in a 16-bit real mode setting when you attempt to run your EXE.

Secondly, note that in the TASM version, they have placed the `Counter` variable in the code segment, and are accessing the `Counter` via an offset from the current code-segment.  You on the other-hand have placed your counter variable `_MyVar` in the BSS section.  Depending on how the linker links your binary executable, that variable may not be accessible from your interrupt ... for instance, it may not be accessible within the 64Kb window of the current data segment when the interrupt is running.  Therefore I would mirror what they did in the TASM version, and place your counter variable in the code-segment, and access it from the code-segment

Comment: I tried using solely 16-bit commands and adding the `.code16` instruction, but it doesn't work (see comments above).
Also, I tried foregoing the variables altogether and using hard-coded constants instead for the screen display bit. Didn't help either.

How do I make my program run in real mode?